# Java DAO Object Transactions

Tags: java, interface, transactions, persistence, dao

I have a question as to how this service and its DAO object are performing persistence transactions.

The service is performing transactions on the database - but it is not using a DAOImpl object - it is instead using an object which is an instance of the interface - and naturally has no implementation of any method signatures. This, in my mind, should not be able to perform any meaningful actions. Am I overlooking something here?

Full link to code

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example

```
@Service
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

  @Autowired
  private UserDAO userDAO;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void insertUser(User user) {
    userDAO.insertUser(user);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public User getUserById(int userId) {
    return userDAO.getUserById(userId);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public User getUser(String username) {
    return userDAO.getUser(username);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userDAO.getUsers();
  }

}


public interface UserDAO {

      void insertUser(User user);

      User getUserById(int userId);

      User getUser(String username);

      List<User> getUsers();
    }


@Service
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public void insertUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
  }

  @Override
  public User getUserById(int userId) {
    return (User) sessionFactory.
      getCurrentSession().
      get(User.class, userId);
  }

  @Override
  public User getUser(String username) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.
      getCurrentSession().
      createQuery("from User where username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    return (User) query.list().get(0);
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.
      getCurrentSession().
      createCriteria(User.class);
    return criteria.list();
  }

}
```

Comment: You're overlooking the basics of Java (and a bit of Spring). Obviously there's a concrete implementation of `UserDAO` injected at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I am still very green at spring. You are referring here to dependency injection? Is this managed through the @autowire annotation & the xml configuration files?

Comment: In this case (with @Autowired) there's probably no xml configuration, but a Java configuration. A suitable bean will be injected to `userDAO` at runtime, or an error will be thrown.

Comment: Got it. I think. I will have to do some reading on how the autowiring works. But why not just declare an instance of the DAOImpl over the DAO itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all , instance of an interface can not be created ,  reference variable can be created for interfaces. Nevertheless ,as i followed the link and found that you are learning Spring with Hibernate. Spring provide you a facility called Dependency Injection which is why there is @Autowire annotation in your UserManagerImpl class which means you have injected a dependency UserDAO in UserManagerImpl class , so on rum time ,spring will provide the instance of the class which implements UserDAO interface .What you are overlooking is thorough study of Spring concepts.by the way all the best .

Comment: Thank you Alok! So, this is essentially to provide more modularity within the code architecture?

Comment: yes , this helps in making your application loosely coupled (i.e. independent classes ). Dependencies can be 'injected' as required .@Jnanathan